# How to export a CSV with lat lon WKT from a layer which is not in WGS84?

Tags: qgis, convert, coordinates, wgs84, linestring

I want to extract a csv with lat and lon coordinates so I select -- Geometry AS_WKT

but when the csv is created I see this

```
LINESTRING (277054.55782319931 198725.03588318737,277052.43701817648 198727.04506689325,277051.7672902745 198729.38911455008,277052.54863949347 198732.73775405987,277055.89727900323 198738.0955772755,277070.40805021225 198755.06201745835,277088.71394619904 198776.60493163791,277099.76445658127 198789.77624704302,277108.91740457463 198800.82675742527,277114.94495569228 198807.97052171279,277118.40521651902 198811.98888912454,277119.96791495691 198813.66320887941)
```

which is not the lat and lon I expected. I chose the crs wgs 84  epsg 4326, but it doesnt work. Any idea?
The lat and lon should be for somewhere in the UK

Comment: Make sure that the coordinates are in 4326, the ones you posted are not longitude latitude...

Comment: You have to find out which coordinate system the data is in - probably some British national grid, and then project the layer to WGS 84.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates look like OSGB1936 British National grid, in Southern Wales.

Saving as WKT does not change the CRS to WGS84. `Set Layer CRS` is **NOT** the right tool either.

You might want to start again from scratch to get it right. Go to `Settings -> Options, CRS` tab, and select `Prompt for CRS`.

Loading the data as delimited text, choose EPSG:27700 if you are asked for it. Then Rightclick `Save As ...` to EPSG:4326 under a different name.

With Rightclick on the layer, `Properties, Metadata` tab, you should find the reprojected extent:

```
xMin,yMin -3.77945,51.6738 : xMax,yMax -3.77849,51.6746
```

Comment: I ve done exactly that and the result is as shown.  any clues?